# Did/do the dinosaurs in Jurassic Park reproduce asexually or did some turn into males?

Tags: biology, jurassic-park, dinosaurs

I remember them saying the dinos were all female to prevent reproduction, but that they reproduced anyhow because of frog DNA used to make them. I thought at first this meant some turned into males to breed with the remaining females, but somehow or another I realized that meant they may have reproduced asexually instead.

Which is the case? And are there males now or is parthenogenesis still going on?

Comment: https://jurassicoutpost.com/jurassic-world-breeding-males-and-females/

Comment: Doing a frog search "protogyny" is the term for female to male switching.  Also some frogs are "sequential hermaphrodites" where a female changes to male after breeding as a female.

Comment: May also be relevant that crocodilians don't have sex chromosomes and gender is determined by environmental conditions like nest temperature.

Comment: There is a fan theory out there that velociraptor called The Big One turned male and impregnated the other ones, which is where the nests/eggshells/baby tracks in the first movie came from. Can't recall where I saw it or if it was ever addressed by any of the filmmakers. But certainly in the case of Site B there are supposed to be male/female dinos (the T-rex pair in TLW and the quilled male raptors in JP3).

Comment: Someone I knew who grew up on a farm said that changing sex was something he saw in chickens. He may have been observing just a change in behavior but maybe female chickens (perhaps born not completely normal) actually can become fertile males.

Comment: @releseabe it's not impossible.  And on the jurassic park front if birds default male a dinosaur probably should too. (If the ovary malfunctions a female bird would switch to male) 
 https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-40016817

Comment: @releseabe I've myself seen chickens turn into roosters when there were no surviving roosters in a flock (we had free range chickens and predators took their share). Whether those roosters were fertile or not I don't know, but they had all the visual characteristics of roosters as well as the temperament and behaviour.

Comment: @jwenting: The fascinating thing about what u have said is that it might have been a response to the absence of males. 25 years ago I read of salamanders which respond to overpopulation/foot shortages by some individuals becoming larger and cannibalistic. This idea is so compelling that I am sure some scifi stories using this have been written; it is not impossible that at some point in human history this occurred -- origin of monster folk tales.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Doctor Grant, in the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park_(novel)) surmises that some of the dinosaurs have turned male, then impregnated the remaining females. At no point does he seem to change his opinion;

> “It's not frog DNA,” Grant said. “It's amphibian DNA. But the
> phenomenon happens to be particularly well documented in frogs.
> Especially West African frogs, if I remember.”
>
> “What phenomenon is that?”
>
> “Gender transition,” Grant said. “Actually, it's just plain changing sex.” Grant explained that a number of plants and animals
> were known to have the ability to change their sex during
> life-orchids, some fish and shrimp, and now frogs. Frogs that had been
> observed to lay eggs were able to change, over a period of months,
> into complete males. They first adopted the fighting stance of males,
> they developed the mating whistle of males, **they stimulated the
> hormones and grew the gonads of males, and eventually they
> successfully mated with females.**
>
> “You're kidding,” Gennaro said. “And what makes it happen?”
>
> “Apparently the change is stimulated by an environment in which all the animals are of the same sex. In that situation, some of the
> amphibians will spontaneously begin to change sex from female to
> male.”
>
> “And you think that's what happened to the dinosaurs?”
>
> “Until we have a better explanation, yes,” Grant said. “I think that's what happened. Now, shall we find this nest?”

Answer (score 7):

@Valorum has answered for the book. In the film [Grant says](https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/Jurassic_Park_Film_Transcript), on finding some hatched eggs in the wild:

> Well, on the tour, the film said they used frog DNA to fill in the
> gene sequence gaps. They mutated the dinosaurs' genetic code and
> blended it with that of frogs. Some species of West African frog are
> known to spontaneously change sex from male to female in a single-sex
> environment. [chuckles a bit] Malcolm was right. Look.

I suppose it’s only a theory and it isn’t actually confirmed, but he seems to think it plausible enough that some of the dinos changed their sex.

Answer (score 4):

I know there's already an accepted answer on this BUT parthenogenesis is also taking place.

It's explicitly mentioned in *Jurassic World: Dominion*.  Owen says that since the raptor Blue was created in part with "Monitor DNA" she can have offspring via parthenogenesis, which is how they explain Blue having a baby raptor despite Blue being the only raptor around.

The female-to-male transitioning is also happening based not only on the statements from the first book/movie but also in later films the audience is told about male dinosaurs (the "buck" T-Rex comes to mind).  So theoretically whether a certain dinosaur species can change male/female or females reproduce without males depends on what sort of "extra" DNA was added when the dinosaur species was first created.

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding a direct quote of the relevant dialogue.